# Nodester: "failed-to-start" new app

Tags: node.js, websocket, nodester

Using nodester, I'm having issues starting a new app. I've created it but the state is: failed-to-start, and it doesn't let me change anything. Anybody have an familiarity with this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's what I got. My current version of nodejs is v0.6.6

Answer (score 1):

### Get available port or one assigned by node PaaS

I suspect you've not used the designated listening port number for your nodester app (it's displayed when you create the app, along with the git repo url). Replace your port variable with this code:

`var port = process.env.app_port || process.env.port || 31337`

That should ensure that your app will deploy on most node PaaS (everyone else seems to use port, nodester's the exception). It will also allow you to run your app locally on port 31337.

background info: https://github.com/nodester/nodester/wiki/App-Environment

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue which didn't allow windows users to immediately create and deploy apps. That is resolved now. See http://blog.nodester.com/post/19908106874/new-nodester-cli-fixes-windows-git-issue